# Garage Band won’t open

Tags: macos

I’m having trouble opening Garage Band version 4.1.2 on macOS version 10.4.11.  It’s only happening on my main partition. If I open using another account it’s fine.

At one point I had installed a Windows partition with `wine bottle` and/or `wine` and I got rid of it because it was causing too many problems. Could that be a problem?

I’m also using a Digidesign M Box 2 Pro from 2007 with ProTools 7.4.

The thing is I have the Korg Legacy Analog Collection 2007 and sometimes want to create patches on Garageband which is infinitely easier than opening a session on ProTools. I can only keep using a demo version that locks after thirty days. On my main partition I have the license. How can I make so everyone can use the Korg software. That’s the only thing that bothers me. My Mac is an Intel IMac 17”.

Here's the crash screen:

[image]

Comment: wine does not use or create a windows partition. I would stickj with the working new user and apps as you need them to that user

Comment: Please indicate the model of Mac you are using. This Digidesign M Box Pro 2 device uses FireWire 400 ports, which are quite antiquated.